# calling more than one function on the same button does not work for me (ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

i got a ajax procedure that is working ok, but now i need to add a new function to be called just once. so i add this to my current script to get the apex collection clean, but now nothing happens, i placed an alert to verify, but no alert is shown, i guess is because i am placing my ***clean script*** in wrong place or there must be something else missing.

```
           // Clean Collection
            function()
             {
                     alert('Clean All');
                     var ajaxRequestd = new htmldb_Get(null,&APP_ID.,"APPLICATION_PROCESS=DEL_PRODUCTS",&APP_PAGE_ID.);
                     ajaxResult = ajaxRequestd.get();
             }
```

here is my full script. thanks for your value tips !!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Totals</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() 
{

        $("#Calculate").click
           (


            function()
             {

           // Clean Collection
            function()
             {
                     alert('Clean All');
                     var ajaxRequestd = new htmldb_Get(null,&APP_ID.,"APPLICATION_PROCESS=DEL_PRODUCTS",&APP_PAGE_ID.);
                     ajaxResult = ajaxRequestd.get();
             }

              $("input[name=f_qty]").each
                (
                 function()
                   {
                     var valueInCurrentTextBox = $(this).val(); 
                     var productId = $(this).parents('tr').find("input[name=f_prod_id]").val();
                     $("#P12_PRODUCT_ID").val(productId);     


                     if (valueInCurrentTextBox != '')
                        {
                          $("#P12_QTY").val(valueInCurrentTextBox);    


                          var ajaxRequest = new htmldb_Get(null,&APP_ID.,"APPLICATION_PROCESS=ADD_PRODUCTS",&APP_PAGE_ID.);
                          ajaxRequest.add('P12_PRODUCT_ID',html_GetElement('P12_PRODUCT_ID').value);
                          ajaxRequest.add('P12_QTY',html_GetElement('P12_QTY').value);

                          ajaxResult = ajaxRequest.get();


                       }
                   }


                );
                alert('Updated!');
              }


           );

}
);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="totals"></div>
<p align="center" style="clear: both;">
<button type="button" style="font-weight: bold;background-color:lightgray;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block;margin-top:0%;margin-bottom:0%" id="Calculate">Add Products</button>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *declaring* that inner function, but never actually calling it. You could assign it to a variable and then call *that*, but it's actually not needed at all.

Try:

```
$(function() 
{
    $("#Calculate").click
    (
      function()
      {
        // Clean Collection
        alert('Clean All');
        var ajaxRequestd = new htmldb_Get(null,&APP_ID.,"APPLICATION_PROCESS=DEL_PRODUCTS",&APP_PAGE_ID.);
        ajaxResult = ajaxRequestd.get();

        $("input[name=f_qty]").each
        (
          function()
          {
            var valueInCurrentTextBox = $(this).val(); 
            var productId = $(this).parents('tr').find("input[name=f_prod_id]").val();
            $("#P12_PRODUCT_ID").val(productId);     

            if (valueInCurrentTextBox != '')
            {
              $("#P12_QTY").val(valueInCurrentTextBox);    

                var ajaxRequest = new htmldb_Get(null,&APP_ID.,"APPLICATION_PROCESS=ADD_PRODUCTS",&APP_PAGE_ID.);
                ajaxRequest.add('P12_PRODUCT_ID',html_GetElement('P12_PRODUCT_ID').value);
                ajaxRequest.add('P12_QTY',html_GetElement('P12_QTY').value);

                ajaxResult = ajaxRequest.get();
            }
          }
        );

        alert('Updated!');
      });
});
```

Comment: You were Right Paul. Thanks a lot !!